# View syscalls/kernel activity for I/O from a running process

Tags: linux, kernel, nfs, io, disk

I'd like to be able to view syscalls or kernel activity for a process...I'm not actually sure of the terminology I need here!  Specifically I'm looking for the difference between I/O going to local disk and I/O going to an NFS export. So I'd like to run e.g. dd against a local and be able to see detailed information about how the system is performing I/O. I want to see the differences between how the system reads and writes to local disk vs a network location - SCSI calls vs NFS calls.

Using a tool like dstat I'm able to see disk I/O compared to network I/O (and can see an obvious difference), but I'm not able to see any details around what is really happening.  I've found a lot of other stats tools but I'm not really looking for stats.

I've tried using strace but it appears this doesn't go "deep" enough as dd against local disk and NFS look identical.

Is there any tool or setting that I can use to see differences at this level?  This is a personal lab set up with CentOS, so I can do as much digging and breaking as necessary.

Comment: The term you're probably looking for is "I/O Profiling" I would suggest using `blktrace` for local storage which will give you the pid associated with the workload.

Comment: That's a great tool but not really what I was looking for - namely because as far as I can tell it only works with block devices and not NFS.

Comment: Hence why it was just a comment. Someone else might know more about profiling I/O to NFS so I was putting it out there for the local storage part of the equation in case there are multiple tools you need to use to do this.